# List of .options for quarto presentations with powerpoint output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

Is there a good place for quarto presentation documentation, particularly the .options or .objects associated with that format. E.g., `{.column width="50%"}` changes the width parameter of the column layout object in Powerpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are having the wrong idea about `.column` and `width=50%`. These are not some format-specific options (and that's why you will not find them [here](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/presentations/pptx.html)). `.column` or `.anyName` are passed as a class to the pandoc Divs (`:::`) and `width` or any `key=val` are passed to pandoc Div as an attribute and Quarto has some lua filters to preprocess the output based on the `.column width="50%"` (which is in this case "Creating a div with width half of the document").

Comment: Thanks @shafee , I wasn’t sure if those were quarto-isms or one of its dependencies. So then is there a pandoc reference you recommend that lists these divs?

Comment: @Maël, I think your pointers are for yaml options rather than the inline divs but might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@MickaelCanouil](https://twitter.com/MickaelCanouil) of [Amazing Quarto](https://github.com/mcanouil/awesome-quarto) fame, I was able to print a copy of the default PPTX reference file and get a good look at documentation for div names. Hope to run down how to change fontsize for each column div from there. More info here:

- [Mickael's post](https://twitter.com/MickaelCanouil/status/1628807581425668096?s=20), see first link for how to call for default template
- pandoc documentation to get [pptx default template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL%202.html#options-affecting-specific-writers)
- pandoc documentation to get [`{.div-attribute}`(s)](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL%202.html)

Not a complete answer, but close enough to being on the right path to close this question.